# Using UIWebView in a UITableViewCell to display dynamic content

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I need to display non-editable text with different styles and colors in table view cells.  In researching, it seems that UIWebView is the way to achieve the style/color flexibility that I want.  Here is what I did: (note iOS 5, XCode 4)

- Created a class WebViewTableViewCell derived from UITableViewCell.  The class contains a UIWebView.
- In storyboard, I created the table view controller with 1 dynamic cell prototype containing a UIWebView object.  The cell is of type WebViewTableViewCell.  I made the connection between the class UIWebView and the storyboard.
- In the table view controller code, overrode "heightForRowAtIndexPath" and used "sizeThatFits" to dynamically adjust the cell height

When I run, all of this "works", except that the cells do not resize to fit all of the text contained in the web view.  In fact they do not resize at all; they are the height as drawn in the storyboard.  Here is some sample code:

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
  WebViewTableViewCell *webCell = (WebViewTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellid"];
  // Now populate the cell with dynamic data
  NSDictionary *thisData = [self.dynamicData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *myString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.  %@",
                          [thisData objectForKey:@"key1"],
                          [thisData objectForKey:@"key2"]];
  [webCell.webView loadHTMLString:myStringbaseURL:nil];
  cell = webCell;
  return cell;
```

heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    WebViewTableViewCell *webCell = (WebViewTableViewCell *) [self tableView:a_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Now that we have the cell, let it determine what its height should be.
    CGFloat rowHeight = 45; // default unless if a problem accessing the cell
    if( webCell )
    {
      CGSize size = [webCell.webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
      rowHeight = rowHeight < size.height ? size.height : rowHeight;
    }
```

One more thing - the cells, although not the correct height, are scrollable.  I want to make them a fixed height and not scrollable.

Any thoughts?

--John

Answer (score 0):

To disable scrolling you can just set `tableView.scrollEnabled = NO`. To get the correct height you can set your view controller as the webview `delegate`, and do something like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var height = 0; for (var i=0; i < document.all.length; i++) { document.all[i].height; if (document.all[i].height > height) { height = document.all[i].height; } }"];
    CGFloat height  = [result floatValue];
}
```

I'm sorry about the big JavaScript, but I think it will work. However, I recommend you to use the built in `UILabel` that supports `NSAttributedString`, or an open source `UILabel` subclass if you support iOS versions prior to 6.

Answer (score -4):

[Here](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/)  is a better aproach to custom tableview.